# In photoshop how do I create an obfuscated window like this

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to make a carbonless invoice for a client, however I need to create something like below to 'blank out' parts of the invoice on the copies. How would I fill a shape with random numbers, in Photoshop?

[image]

Comment: Hi MikeF, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you please tell us what you have tried that didn't work, and why? Thanks! If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I would suggest you reconsider the application of choice. Consider using InDesign or illustrator instead

Comment: To be clear, you're designing your invoice in Photoshop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure whether you'd be able to create random numbers in Photoshop. You could, however, lay out a text layer with an externally created batch of random numbers:

- create a text box much larger than the area you intend to cover;
- paste in the random numbers from elsewhere;
- using the <kbd>Window > Character</kbd> palette, set the leading to 25~35% of the point size--somewhat dependent upon the font chosen. So for 24pts text, you'd use a leading of 6~8pts;
- Fill the text box with some more random numbers, as there's more space now;
- Add a mask to the layer to clip it neatly on the sides;

For good measure, you can copy the layer and rotate it 90° and apply the mask to both of them.

Comment: I think this would be much more productive to do in illustrator´with the symbol sprayer tool. Come to think about it invoice screms illustrator or in design.

Comment: yet, the OP explicitly asked for Photoshop. :)

Comment: ...then maybe you'd better add that as a comment to the question? :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new square canvas
2. Create a text box containing `0123456789`
3. Duplicate the layer, positioning it and rotating randomly over and over again until you get the required uniformity and density
4. Make a repeating pattern using a technique such as [this](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/repeating-patterns-intro/).

Alternatively you could try creating a brush with the same text and tweak settings appropriately.

Comment: Good answer. I would also add that you can use a layer mask or select a part of the pattern and delete the inverse to create a strip as shown in the image.